# How to add action into the drop-down menu in django

Tags: django, django-admin

I've got a model like below:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(verbose_name='Mobile Number')
    register_date = models.DateTimeField('Registration Date', auto_now=True)
    Email_addr = models.EmailField()
```

The admin.py is like this:

```
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ['username', 'phone_number', 'register_date', 'Email_addr']
    search_fields = ['username']
    list_display = ['username', 'phone_number', 'Email_addr']
    actions = ['some_actions']
```

As you know, in the dropdown menu there is one built-in action called Delete action.
How could I add another action to this dropdown menu like edit and how to write the action for this embedded action?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm going to have something like list_filter where the rows is shown. and then user could add, delete and edit row in the page list_filter is placed. I don't want user to click on row, then in another page does edit. I need everything to be done in one page itself